# Save background color in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I want to save my page background-color in a cookie.
A user can choose a color from a list, but when refreshing the page the color must stay

I could finally make it work that when i press a color from the list a cookie value turns to blue

```
 $("#panel .blue").on('click', function(){
     if ($.cookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' }) !== null) { 
         $.removeCookie("the_cookie", { path: '/' });
         $.cookie('color_cookie', 'blue', {expires:7, path:'/'}); 
     }
 });
```

Now I'm just wondering when I load my page how I can check that value **blue** and make my background in that same color?

Or should I take a complete other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: try HTML5 Web Storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you don't have anything weird in your css: First of all, you need to retrieve the value of the cookie that you store and set it into your div like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yourDiv").css("background-color",$.cookie('color_cookie'));
});
```